# How do you find the most probable state path given an observed sequence with infinite emissions values in MATLAB?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, matlab, hidden-markov-model

I have created code to output observed values of a Hidden Markov Model.  I see that 'hmmviterbi' would give you the most probable state sequence given an observed sequence, transmission matrix, and emission matrix.  Is there a way to use this function if you don't have an emission matrix?  My emission values are pulled from a normal distribution with mean dependent on 3 different states and standard deviation 1.  If there is no way around to use 'hmmviterbi', how can you code on your own to produce the most probable state sequence?  I am unsure how to deal with the infinite emission values.  Here is my code for the initial HMM:

````
N = 3; %%the three states are [-1 0 1]
%A is transition prob matrix
A = [.99,.005,.005;.005,.990,.005;.005,.005,.990];
%pi is initial state vector
pi = [1/3,1/3,1/3];
%T is # of observations per simulation
T = 1000;
%n is # of simulations
n = 5;
%Allocate space for the state matrix
State = zeros(n,T);
Observe = zeros(n,T);
%loop over # of simulations

for i=1:1:n
    x = rand(1);
    if x <= (1/3)
        State(i,1) = 1;
    elseif x > (1/3) && x <= (2/3)
        State(i,1) = 2;
    else
        State(i,1) = 3;
    end
    if State(i,1) == 1
        b = -1;
    elseif State(i,1) == 2
        b = 0;
    else
        b = 1;
    end

    Observe(i,1)= normrnd(b,1);
for k=2:1:T
    State(i,k) = randsample(3, 1, true, A(State(i,k-1),:));
    if State(i,k) == 1
        c = -1;
    elseif State(i,k) == 2
        c = 0;
    else
        c = 1;
    end
    Observe(i,k)= normrnd(c,1);
end
end
for i = 1:1:n
    for k = 1:1:T
        if State(i,k)==1
            State(i,k)=-1;
        elseif State(i,k)==2
            State(i,k)=0;
        else
            State(i,k)=1;
        end
    end
end
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it seems you cannot use the *hmmviterbi* function of Matlab with continuous observations.
The algorithm of Viterbi is given on page 8 of this [famous tutorial on HMM](https://www.ece.ucsb.edu/Faculty/Rabiner/ece259/Reprints/tutorial%20on%20hmm%20and%20applications.pdf). Or you might find other documents easily with a google search.

As for your precise point on how to handle the emission values : in the continuous case, you do not have a transition matrix $B$, whose elements are the $b_{S_j}(O_i)$, representing probability of the (discrete) observation $O_i$ conditioned on the discrete state $S_j$. Instead, $b_{S_j}(O_i)$ will be taken as the probability density function of the gaussian distribution, evaluated at the (continuous) value $O_i$, with mean parametrized by the hidden state $S_j$ and standard-deviation of 1. This is done by *normpdf* in Matlab

(The good news in your problem is that you do not have to estimate the parameters!)

Comment: Hey! I am just getting back to this.  I need help on how to handle "the mean parametrized by the hidden state".  When coding the probability using "normpdf",  I have an observation value, the standard deviation, but the mean chosen for each pass will be another probability or random choice?  This part is confusing me, I do not know how to code correctly.

Comment: In the discrete case, you have an emission matrix $B$ which works just like the transition matrix $A$ in your code sample. In the continuous case, you have $b_{S_j}(O_i) = \mathcal{N}(O_i,\mu_{S_j},\sigma_{S_j})$, i.e. the gaussian distribution whose mean and standard-deviation depends on the hidden state, evaluated at point $O_i$. In matlab this would give, using your notations: `normpdf(Observe(n,t), mu(State(n,t)), 1)`, for all simulations `n` for all instants `t`, where `mu` is a vector containing different means.

Comment: Oh!  I was under the assumption I wasn't 'allowed' to access my State matrix.

Comment: Well, it depends which operations/algorithm you are working with, but the parameters of the gaussians do depend on the hidden states